# Is this integral calculated correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$.

The proof of my textbook says that: Let $t=\frac{x}{a},dt=d(\frac{x}{a})$,

Then we have $\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{a\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{a})^2}}=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin t+C=\arcsin\frac{x}{a}+C$.

I think it's not right. It dosen't consider the condition that $a<0$, and if then I have the following process:

$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{-a\sqrt{1-(\frac{x}{a})^2}}=-\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=-\arcsin t+C=-\arcsin\frac{x}{a}+C^{'}$.

It's different from the former result.

Comment: You are right. The correct answer is $\arcsin (\frac x {|a|})+C$ if $a \neq 0$

Comment: And indeed, their specific mistake seems to be writing $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ as $a\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}$ instead of the correct $|a|\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what happens, for $~a\ne0~,$
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int \frac{dx}{|a|\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}}$$
Now substitute $~t=\frac{x}{|a|}\implies dt=d\left(\frac{x}{|a|}\right)=\frac{dx}{|a|}~,$ which gives$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\arcsin(t)+c=\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{|a|}\right)+c$$ where $~c~$ is arbitrary constant.